# Haxe/OpenFL in FlashBuilder/Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, flash-builder, haxe, openfl

I am looking for a possible solution of developing Haxe/OpenFL applications on a Mac.
While Windows has [a very good IDE](http://www.flashdevelop.org), the Macs are left much weaker support.
I tried every IDE I could find for mac that has a Haxe plug-in, but they often lack basic features and are pretty outdated and buggy.

Is there a way to install Haxe SDK and have an ability to use OpenFL API on Flash Builder (4.7 would be best)? Flash Builder is based on Eclipse, maybe I can find plug-in for Eclipse?

If not, how does one write their own plug-in?

**NOTE:** I know of Win emulators that helps to run [FD](http://www.flashdevelop.org) on a Mac, but I cannot have that option right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a Haxe bundle for SublimeText 2 and i think it's quite complete for Haxe development

https://github.com/clemos/haxe-sublime-bundle

Lots of developer also say that IntelliJ is a way to go http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/
But i have never try it yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of IDEs over here:
 http://haxe.org/com/ide

I'm not sure how up-to-date the list is. If you want to build an editor, consider joining this project http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/cactus-ide

Comment: http://haxe.org/com/ide is very outdated. I'd say 2011 was last update to this list. All of these IDEs are buggy and cannot even complete syntax's correctly. And now when you need to have lime to run openfl most of these IDEs aren't even supporting haxe with openfl and NME is not a viable option anymore.